# Attach multiple files to the same email message

Tags: c#

I need to send some Pdf files as email attachments stored in a database.

[image]

To do this, run a query in the table for the Select field (*where*) **Coding** and **DateCoding** and a **While** loop in which I create a list with paths contained in **PdfCoding** separated by commas:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{                                
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        PdfCoding = reader["PdfCoding"].ToString();
        string[] itemList = Regex.Split(PdfCoding, @"(?=D:)").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
        Commaseplist = String.Join(", ", itemList);
        Response.Write(Commaseplist);
     }
}
```

Now the **Commaseplist** contains this string with all paths contained in **PdfCoding**:

```
D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\015.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\016.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\017.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\018.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\019.pdf
```

But when I try to attach all the PDF files by:

```
foreach (string value in itemList)
{
    mailMessagePlainText.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(value.ToString()));
}
```

As an attachment in the email message I find only files **019.pdf**, that is the last on the list **Commaseplist**.

Please help me.

**Edit #1**

The string in **Commaseplist** is:

```
D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\015.pdf,D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\016.pd‌​f, D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\017.pdf,D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\018.pdf, D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\019.pdf,
```

when I try to attach all the PDF files by:

```
mailMessagePlainText.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Commaseplist.ToString()));
```

I have this error:

```
Could not find file 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\019.pdf,'
```

Comment: Where are the commas? D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\015.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\016.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\017.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\018.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\019.pdf

Comment: This is the problem? How to insert the commas in the string of list ? What a wrong? Is not sufficient `String.Join(", ", itemList);` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  string Commaseplist = @"D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\015.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\016.pdfD:\ine‌​tpub\wwwroot\app\public\017.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\018.pdfD:\inetpub\ww‌​wroot\app\public\019.pdf";
  string[] itemList = Commaseplist.Replace(".pdf", ".pdf,").TrimEnd(',').Split(',');
  MailMessage mailMessagePlainText = new MailMessage();
  foreach (string value in itemList)
  {
       mailMessagePlainText.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(value));
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Good catch Jeremy. I was just going to comment about removing the last comma.

Comment: `CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'string.TrimEnd(params char[])' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: See edited answer. Needed to replace TrimEnd(",") with TrimEnd(',').

Comment: Thanks, but in the output I have:`D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\015.pdf,D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\016.pdf,
D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\017.pdf,D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\018.pdf,
D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\019.pdf,`

Comment: Is this not what you want? The last comma should be stripped off by the TrimEnd(',').

Comment: Please see **Edit #1** in my first question, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91000/discussion-between-thewisegod-and-antonio-mailtraq).

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq that error with TrimEnd expecting a char not a string was my fault. Apologies both.

Answer (score 0):

I think life is already difficult why complicated more ? ...

For your problem I suggest:

1. In your method sql query you need create an a List string and add each single path for pdf file:

   ```
       List<string> pdfList = new List<string>();

       ...

       if (reader.HasRows)
       {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               pdfList.Add(reader["PdfCoding"].ToString());                                    
           }
       }
   ```
2. In your method for send email :

   ```
   //Start
   foreach (string file in pdfList)
   {
       mailMessagePlainText.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file));
   }
   //End
   ```

Hope this helps!

Happy coding !